# What are the differences between FFN, VFN, GMVFN and ZMVFN PDF schemes in QCD?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, definition, quantum-chromodynamics, partons

What are the differences between the fixed flavour number (FFN), variable flavour number (VFN), general-mass variable flavour number (GMVFN) and zero-mass variable flavour number (ZMVFN) schemes for parton distribution functions (PDFs) in QCD?

I see these words used alot in papers but upon googling I could not find material that properly explains the differences between these schemes without delving into too much details. I would like to have an overview that boils all the details down to the crucial differences between these schemes. How do they differ in their assumptions, their validity regimes and in how they work?

Comment: I found that section 2.7 of this thesis gives a *very* cursory introduction into the different schemes you mention http://nnpdf.mi.infn.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/ZahariKassabov_phd_unimi.pdf

Comment: Indeed, that's basically what I was looking for. May I ask how one can find such theses? Is there a database one can browse such as arxiv? I understand that most theses are not published on arxiv, let alone in journals and the like.

Comment: I went to the NNPDF collaboration page to see if they had any review papers, and saw that thry had a list of theses written about this kind of stuff, so I more or less jist went through a couple and this one seemed good